# Invoking trigger without any changes in the existing records or creating a new record

Tags: apex, trigger, design-patterns

Is it possible to invoke a trigger without making any changes to the existing records or without creating a new record?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly, but there's a design pattern that will get you pretty close to that. You can setup the trigger to invoke another Class/Method. That other Class is usually referred to as a "Trigger Handler". A common example might be a Class named "AccountTriggerHandler".

Think of the Trigger as the "boss" directing the TriggerHandler "worker" to do the heavy lifting.

The nice thing about this design pattern is it allows you call the TriggerHandler Class directly, without going having to fire the trigger with a DML operation. (There are other advantages too!)

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a trigger stems from databases, and are tied to the CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) actions (except for 'reading', I don't think any database allows you to trigger on a read).

Apex is the same, there is no way to execute a trigger without performing an insert, update, deletion, or un-deletion.

This is one reason to keep logic out of triggers (and instead create classes to perform the logic, which are themselves called from the trigger).

In some situations, you may also be able to perform what I call a 'blind update'. Put simply, you gather some records (usually in a `List`) and perform a DML `update` on that list without making any changes to the records before calling `update` (hence, you aren't really looking through the records, you're 'blind' to what they actually contain). Even if there aren't any changes happening, this will cause `before update` and `after update` triggers to run.

Comment: I think you have coined a new term there. I've used the 'blind update' method before, but I didn't know what to call it... now I do! Thanks!

Comment: I tend to call it an *empty* update.

Answer (score 1):

The `Handler` pattern is great to bring up and will allow you to simulate an entire trigger event in one go (without hitting the database). But you can go a step further and implement a `Service` layer and cherry pick specific data transformations you want to simulate, if you want that level of granularity. It sure makes testing easier. Here's an example:

```
public static void setSomeFlag(List<Opportunity> records)
{
    for (Opportunity record : records)
        record.Some_Checkbox__c = true;
}
```

Notice how this field update doesn't actually commit anything to the database. Since you would call it from a `before` trigger, and the transformation will just "tag along" and stick with the transaction. With cross-object updates, usually you would write them so it does commit the database operation and call them from an `after` trigger, but the concept is the same.

With this design pattern, testing in particular becomes quite easy, and most of your tests do exactly what you requested in your question: simulate trigger actions without hitting the database. Your service layer can go into incredible detail to ensure application performance without the performance hit of constant database interaction, and then you just need some cursory trigger testing to verify that the `Service` layer got hooked in properly.